# Taxonomies missing from list but still in database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I've built a WordPress site with custom posts. The posts have Categories and tags. At some in the the past couple of weeks all the taxonomies have disappeared from the list in admin and therefore not showing on the front end thus breaking the website.

I've setup the same site on another server and tested with an older version of the database and that works. When I upload the latest version of the database that when all the taxonomies seem sot awol.

You can still see the taxonomies in the parent drop down and also when out go to create a new post you can see them on the right hand column.

I've also turned all plugins on and off again with no effect.

One change I do remember is WordPress asking me to update the WordPress database version a week or so ago. Since then new posts have been added,  I don't know if this would corrupt the database or not?

Can anyone shed any light on this that might help me fix the issue?

Below is a screenshot of the broken database taxonomies

[image]

Here is a version that uses older but working version of the database...

[image]

I'm using WP version 4.3.1

Plugins installed as follows:

- ACF
- Ajax lazy load
- CPT UI

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem. Suspect it's a bug in ACF?

Answer (score 0):

I things you forgot the `taxonomy` `name` or `slug` and `custom post type` attach and When do all `taxonomy` display

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you mean but i've added another screen shot above to show the older but working version of the database. Sometime in the last 2 weeks the database may have been corrupted by a WordPress update.

Comment: correct, i have two sites the same for testing and debugging. One has the broken database and the other has the working database. The broken database has the most recent version with latest posts. The working database doesn't not have all the posts that i need.